# Rich Text is not Wrapping in Wrap Widget

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a card with a list of items arranged within a wrapped widget that should be in a vertical order. I attempted to set the direction property to Axis.vertical, which successfully aligned the items vertically one by one. However, the text did not wrap as expected, as illustrated below.

**Without direction property :**

[image: With direction]

**With direction Property :**

[image: With Direction property]

**Reference code :**

```
Card(
        child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
            child: Wrap(
              runSpacing: 3,
              direction : Axis.vertical,
              children: [
                Icon(Icons.memory),
                RichText(
                  text: TextSpan(
                      text: 'Title : ',
                      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.titleSmall,
                      children: [
                        TextSpan(
                            text: 'Memory',
                            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyMedium)
                      ]),
                ),
                RichText(
                  softWrap: true,
                  text: TextSpan(
                      text: 'Des : ',
                      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.titleSmall,
                      children: [
                        TextSpan(
                            text:
                                'Currently used memory 250 GB remaining is 250 GB ..... !!!!',
                            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyMedium)
                      ]),
                )
              ],
            )))
```

[Dart pad reference code](https://dartpad.dev/?id=a6820e89b2c9b958fda102c3fd3e7461)

**Note** : We can utilize the column along with the Expand/Flexible widget to wrap the text, but I prefer not to do that. By employing the Wrap widget, we can easily achieve equal spacing between the widgets, making it my preferred choice. Kindly provide solution with Wrap widget only

Answer (score 0):

If You want to successfully align the items vertically one by one, You must Wrap RicheText to Sizedbox or Container Widget.
because Flutter want to max width or max length in on line.
So you wrap RichText to Sixedbox or Container and setting `width` property, They successfully align the items with Wrap widget

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

const Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue,
      ),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: const Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: MyWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyWidget({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GridView.builder(
        itemCount: 6,
        gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
            crossAxisCount: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width > 600 ? 3 : 2),
        itemBuilder: (_, index) => Card(
            child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                child: Wrap(
                  runSpacing: 3,
                  direction : Axis.vertical,
                  children: [
                    const Icon(Icons.memory),
                    RichText(
                      text: TextSpan(
                          text: 'Title : ',
                          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.titleSmall,
                          children: [
                            TextSpan(
                                text: 'Memory',
                                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyMedium)
                          ]),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 200,
                      child: RichText(
                        softWrap: true,
                        text: TextSpan(
                            text: 'Des : ',
                            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.titleSmall,
                            children: [
                              TextSpan(
                                  text:
                                  'Currently used memory 250 GB remaining is 250 GB ..... !!!!',
                                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyMedium)
                            ]),
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ))));
  }
}
```

Result Image
[result image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vPd9b.png)